# Find files given a pattern and permission bits

Tags: shell, find

I am trying to figure out how to list files in a directory beginning with a certain letter and also have certain permissions.

I know how to list/find files beginning with `a` for example.

```
find /[directory-name] -type f -name 'a*'
```

I have also found how to list the permissions of files.

The problem I seem to have is that I don't know how to combine the two together.

My desired outcome would be something along the lines  to display files beginning with `a`, and have the permissions `770`.

Answer (score 0):

it's a little crude, but maybe you can try something like this (Tested on debian):

```
find ./[directory-name] -type f -name 'a*'|xargs stat --format "%a %n"| grep "^770"
```

xargs feeds the results of the find command one by one to stat, which outputs the octal file status and file name (there are a lot of format options available to stat). Finally, grep selects the files with the interesting permissions.

Comment: Look into the `-perm` option of `find(1)`.

Comment: `-perm` will obviate the need for stat and grep.